# Why can't I reach my webserver over the IPv4 address within the local network?

Tags: networking, router, dns, ip, ipv4

I can reach our server from outside, using my public IP address (port forwarding and all that stuff works). What does not work is reaching the server from within my own local network over the IPv4 address. Using my home network address (192.168.xxx.xxx) does work, but IPv4 somehow gets blocked.

I'm pretty sure that this wasn't the same at the place where I lived before. I think something is blocking that somewhere. At this house, my provider put a router before my own router (to which I don't really have access. They use it to provide remote help).

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: It's working as it's suppose too.  Your external public address is only valid outside of your network.  Nothing you describe is abnormal

Comment: @Ramhound But if I connect to google or something, the DNS gets resolved to an IP and I get routed there. How is it not possible to get routed to my own homeserver?

Comment: Are you saying you can't reach the web server using its public IP address from inside your network. Or that you cannot reach the web server using its private IP address from inside your network? If the former, it sounds like a hairpin NAT issue. We would need more technical details about this other router your ISP installed. A router in front of a router begs the question how your port forwarding is setup.

Comment: @Appleoddity I know that I contacted the support once and they "gave the port control to me" which was fine for me back then. Port 443 and 80 are definitely open. I can reach it from outside my local network. `Are you saying you can't reach the web server using its public IP address from inside your network.` <- This is exactly my question.

Comment: That is a hairpin NAT issue. Depending on the hardware, it may or may not be able to do a hairpin NAT. This means, simply, you cannot use the public IP from inside the network. Instead, make a custom DNS entry internally or use the HOSTS file to redirect the host name to the private IP address when you are inside the network. Or just plain use the private IP when inside the network.

Comment: This will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning](https://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

Comment: @Appleoddity This is not a big problem to me. If this is not easily and permanently solvable, I can just use my local IP. I was just wondering what the reason is for this behaviour. @ David: I have one of the newest FritzBox routers, but NAT Hairpinning doesn't tell me anything. Thanks for the link! It doesn't seem to be a safe one though. SSL cert probably expired.

Comment: The site is 100% safe.  A malicious link wouldn't live more then a minute, given that David is a moderator, the link is safe.